# Dataset Preparation in CSV Format

Tags: nlp

I want to prepare a .csv file to identify a person's name present in any document using machine learning.My question is how the dataset is prepared to train the model?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for slot-filling/entities detection in NLU, this may help: [Neural Named Entity Recognition and Slot Filling](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/components/slot_filling.html)